# How to access subclass static methods from Class token?

Tags: java, class, methods, static

The concept I'm having trouble with is how can I pass a token (such as `Apple.class`) into a method, and then get access to the subclass's static methods so I can retrieve generic information about the subclass?(in this case a generic image of an apple)

Here's some Java-like psudocode:

```
abstract class Food {
}         

class Apple extends Food {
  static Image getImage(){
    return (generic image of an apple);
  }
}
class Onion extends Food {
  static Image getImage(){
    return (generic image of an onion);
  }
}

void arrayManager(Class<? extends Food> foodToken){
  useImage(foodToken.getImage()); // <-- can't access static methods from Class token
  storeType(foodToken);
}

//... executing code ...
arrayManager(Apple.class);
arrayManager(Onion.class);
```

The executing code needs to tell the `arrayManager()` what kinds of foods it wants stored.  The `arrayManager()` method displays a simple generic image and stores the token for later reference. But I can't find a way to get a generic image of the specific subclass.

If the `arrayManager()` method wanted to instantiate the passed in token, then no problem, I could just:

```
foodToken.newInstance();
```

And then I could call a non-static version of `GetImage()`.

But it seems absurd to have to instantiate a Food type object (either before the `arrayManager()` call or afterward) when I just want a static method to give me a generic image not associated with a specific Apple instance.  If I store the token and instantiate temporarily to retrieve the image, I have to instantiate and then throw the object away every time I need something from a static method of that subclass. If I instantiate and store the actual object instead of the token, I'm faced with storing thousands of identical objects just to get generic information.

I've been struggling with versions of this issue for weeks. So far I haven't found anything that seems to include the issue of the token having to pass into a method. If my methodology is all wet I'm open to other ways of going about things. I'm hoping I don't have to use a bulky piece of reflection code.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: You could use reflection for this, but wouldn't it be simpler to change it to `arrayManager(Class<? extends Food> foodToken, Image img)`?

Comment: Great suggestion, I didn't think of this idea. Though it does reduce the utility of having the token in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with reflection: (assuming you're in the same package)

```
Method m = foodToken.getMethod("getImage");
Image image = (Image) m.invoke(null);
```

If you're outside of the package, the methods may not be accessible (as defined in your example, at least), but you can use reflection to fix that, too. Use `getDeclaredMethod` instead of `getMethod` in that case, and call `setAccessible(true)` to make it accessible to the caller.

Comment: This is a great answer, I didn't know this could be done. Thank you. The only drawback I can see is that if the `getImage()` method is renamed, it breaks the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with Reflection.  If you want an easy way to do this I have an open source lightweight library which has no 3rd party dependencies and is on Maven Central.

Checkout Reflect which has full Recipe examples: https://github.com/gondor/reflect

Doing this with Reflect:

```
Image image = Reflect.on(Reflect.on(foodToken.getClass()).mutators().get("image"))
                     .against(foodToken).call();
```

If you prefer not to use any libraries then @Mark Elliots answer is correct